# angular material2 autocomplete option row size

Tags: autocomplete, angular-material2

Is there a directive, style or CSS setting to allow a change of the row size of the options?

The options seem to be spaced pretty far apart.

I was able to change the font & line-height but not the row height.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just add this css?

```
.mat-option {
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

or in an older version of Material:

```
.md-option {
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that when navigating the list with the arrow keys, the list scrolles up much faster then needed because material thinks every option is 48 px height.

Comment: what worked for me was selector: `mat-option { ..css }` (without the period at the beginning)

Answer (score 0):

Within the `<md-option>` tag, you can put an inline style like this `style="height: 30px"`

I have created this [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/AX3kuK6HekrocFujors7) from material2 example.

```
<md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete">
  <md-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state" style="height: 30px">
    {{ state }}
  </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>
```

Comment: It sorta works, but the background and fonts get cut off, reducing the font size puts the background highlight offset between the lines.  I guess I need to mess with the styles a little more.  Thank you very much for your effort and idea for this issue Nehal.

Answer (score 0):

With version 15 I had to do this:

```
.autocomplete-option {
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 12pt;
    min-height: unset;
}
```